# What is the pattern that describes these numbers?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, number-theory

Supposed you are given the following numbers:

- 6
- 28
- 496
- 8128
- 33550336
- 8589869056

What's the relation between them?

Comment: This is not really a puzzle. Generally one should avoid sequences that are easy to find on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000396), especially well known mathematical ones. It then becomes just a trivia question.

Answer (score 1):

They are all

> [Perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) because the numbers are equal to half of the sum of their divisors.

So

> 28 -> (1+2+4+7+14+28)/2 = 28